# Remove last slash from url with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i'd like to redirect this url, from:

```
site.com/cat/prod/orange
to: site.com/cat/prod
or: site.com/cat/prod?color=orange
```

But i need to keep the last slash as parameter because i need it to a query.
is it possibile?
I use wordpress as cms on this project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R] # <- for test, for prod use [L,R=301]
```